# Message collector not working discord js v13

Tags: javascript, discord.js

```
        let filter = m => m.author.id === message.author.id
    const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({filter, time: 15000, max: 1});

    //name
    let name = message.author.username
    gender()
    //gender

    function gender(){
    embed = embed
    .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s About Me setup || Gender`)
    .setDescription('Whats your gender/pronounce?')
    .setColor("BLUE")
    message.reply({embeds: [embed]})


    collector.on('collect', m =>{
        let gender = m.content
        m.channel.send(`${gender}`)
        age()
        })
}

    //age
    function age(){
    embed = embed
    .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s About Me setup || Age`)
    .setDescription('How old are you?')
    .setColor("BLUE")
    message.reply({embeds: [embed]})

    collector.on('collect', m =>{
        let age = m.content
        m.channel.send(`${age}`)
        nationality()
        })
    }
    //nationality
    function nationality() {
    embed = embed
    .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s About Me setup || Nationality`)
    .setDescription('Where are you from?')
    .setColor("BLUE")
    message.reply({embeds: [embed]})

    collector.on('collect', m =>{
        let nationality = m.content
        m.channel.send(`${nationality}`)
        description()
        })
}
    //description
    function description(){
    embed = embed
    .setTitle(`${message.author.username}'s About Me setup || Age`)
    .setDescription('Describe yourself, tell others your favorite hobbies, favorite movies, ect. in less than 1500 characters')
    .setColor("BLUE")
    message.reply({embeds: [embed]})

    collector.on('collect', m =>{
        if(m.content.length > 1500){
            embed = embed
            .setTitle(':warning: Error! :warning:')
            .setDescription('Your description can only be less than 1500 characters')
            .setColor("BLUE")
            message.reply({embeds: [embed]})
            description()    
        }
        let description = m.content
        m.channel.send(`${description}`)
        })
    }
```

hey, so I'm trying to make an about me command where when users say "about me setup" it will run through the setup and ask for information like gender, age, desc, etc. (the message.channel.send is just a placeholder, once I get it to work ill put it in an actual database), but it doesn't seem to work like how I expected it to, here's what happens when I [try to run the command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrSC3.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line:

```js
const collector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({filter, time: 15000, max: 1});
```

Your message collector is only collecting messages for 15 seconds, and it will only collect 1 message.

From the [DiscordJS documentation](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-message-collector), createMessageCollector accepts the following arguments:

- `time`: Amount of time in milliseconds the collector should run for
- `max`: Number of messages to successfully pass the filter
- `maxProcessed`: Number of messages encountered (no matter the filter result)

You can fix this by adjusting those parameters in the creation of your message collector to match your needs, or by reworking your command to accept parameters for gender, age, and nationality and use those parameters to construct the final description response.

On a side note: it looks like you are triggering your bots commands with the `L!` prefix. This is no longer recommended, as Discord has introduced [slash commands](https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/1500000368501-Slash-Commands-FAQ#:%7E:text=Slash%20Commands%20are%20the%20new,command%20right%20the%20first%20time.).

Bots that are in more than 75 servers will not be able to read message content (it's becoming [privileged](https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Privileged-Intent-for-Verified-Bots)). I'd recommend switching to slash commands so that you're using the latest way of providing interactions for your bot. There's a great tutorial showing how to create a bot from scratch using slash commands [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html).

Comment: thanks, but the time is actually 15000 ms which is 15 seconds, and also i do want the max to be just 1, the thing that I want it to do is after lets say we already configured the gender, it will move on to the age, then after that your nationality and so on

Comment: My bad for misreading the milliseconds. Regardless, I'm confident that the max:1 is your problem here as you have defined the collector as a constant at the start, and are re-using it throughout your code. I think you either need to up the max, or use a new collector for each question.

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "use a new collector", i'm sorry but i'm pretty new to this coding thing

Comment: no problem -- what I mean is that you could define several collectors, each of which would wait for one message. You could do this by naming each collector for what it is collecting. For example:
`const genderCollector = message.channel.createMessageCollector({filter, time: 15000, max: 1});`, and then another one for age, nationality, and inside your gender function, you change `collector.on('collect')` to `genderCollector.on('collect')`, etc.

Comment: hey i figured it out, i just asigned a new collector for each part(description, age, ect(i dont know what to call them)), thank you!
edit: I didnt saw your comment, anyways thank you so much

Comment: hey ive encountered another error... so all of those work nicely exept for the filter, assume that "filter" means the code that i provided, and i tried to implement that filter on my new code cuz i forgot about it, so I tried [this](https://pastebin.com/mBqqUfm1), but it dosent work

Comment: i just realised that i already implemented it, eitherway it still dosent work

Comment: nvm figgured it out thanks